# Bootstrap Dropdown not contained in Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I don't think theres any CSS that would change this so I'll just post the HTML.

Anyways my navbar element 'About' has a dropdown menu that stopped working. I couldn't figure it out so I reworked the code till it fixed. However it only fixed it a bit.

Essentially when my navbar collapses the About element is still contained, but when it is clicked and reveals its contents it creates essentially a new frame outside the dropdown box. It used to just enlarge the collapsed menu to show all the elements of the dropdown as well. I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <img id="logo" src="images/logoSM.png" alt="Limit Magazine">
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#" ><div>About<span class="caret"></span></div></a></li>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="story.html">Our Story</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tumblr</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="#"><div class="navsub btn-nav pull-left">Subscribe</div></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is what it ends up looking like.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wLyQbLJ.png]

Answer (score 0):

Modified code is as follows. The `<li>` should contain your dropdown button/pill/etc then should have the full `<ul>` of whats in the dropdown before the dropdown `<li>` is closed. I was missing things.

```
<li class="dropdown" >
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#" ><div>About<span class="caret"></span></div></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="story.html">Our Story</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tumblr</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: You might want to escape the code in the first part of your answer with backticks i.e. \` ... \`